# PHP5.4 code Runs on server but not on local

Tags: php, php-5.4

I got a php code (`index.php`) from a friend, something like this:

```
<?
    if (!isset($_SESSION['stdtype']))
    {
        $datas = mysql_query($query);
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($datas);
        if ($data) {
            ?><li><a href="ext.php" target="_blank">Acc Letter</a></li><?
        }
        else {
            ?><li><a href="user_print_acceptance_letter.php">Acc Letter</a></li><?
        }
    }
    $datas = mysql_query($query2);
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($datas);
    if ($data)code
    {
        ?>
         <li><a href="user_upload_file.php?kat=student">Upload</a></li>
        <?php
    }
        $datas = mysql_query($query3);
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($datas);
        if ($data) {
        if ($data['rank'] <> 6 && $data['rank'] <> 0) {
?>
```

the error is:

> ::1:56706 [500]: /index.php - syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/asd/phpT_T/index.php on line 333

line `333` from above snippet is:

```
    } <-- this one
    $datas = mysql_query($query3);
```

is there anything on `php.ini` that I should add to make the exact copied code from server works on my computer? because my computer already has the same php version (`5.4.45`)

Comment: You probably don't have short tags enabled, so `<?` needs to be `<?php`

Comment: For security reasons, please consider dropping the deprecated `mysql` extension and replace it with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

go up a couple of lines. You will find this:

```
if ($data)code
  {
```

this should be

```
if ($data)
  {
```

Also replace `<?` with `<?php` everywhere in your code

for your code to work